# Do kernel messages go through syslogd or journald?

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, rsyslog, systemd-journald, dmesg

I'm using Debian. Debian ships with rsyslogd for its syslogd. It also ships journald. Does the kernel log to rsyslogd first, or journald?

I want to filter one of the messages out of the logs which is responsible for a lot of spam. Should I [use this method from 2011 which targets rsyslogd](https://askubuntu.com/a/30292/29097), or is there a newer method that would target `journald`?

Comment: Debian uses `journald` then forwards that to `syslog` (at least it used to, newer versions of systemd have stopped documenting the forwarding behavior in systemd.exec(5) ).

Answer (score 2):

The answer probably depends on your Debian version. Look in file
`/etc/rsyslog.conf` and if you see the line

```
$ModLoad imjournal
```

or its equivalent in RainerScript syntax

```
module(load="imjournal")
```

then `rsyslogd` is reading the log files of systemd's journald for the kernel log messages.

There may have been intermediate setups where `journald.conf` was
configured to `ForwardToSyslog=True`, hence writing to
`/run/systemd/journal/syslog`, and rsyslogd would be configured to
use module `imuxsock` to read from there.